# WCF Contract Change IsRequiredMessage

Tags: c#, wcf

Hi i have a contract like the one i attach below this comment, my question is: if i change the error message and/or the range, would i break existing clients?
I've read a few posts, (i.e https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384251.aspx)  but i still can't figure this out.
Thanks in advance!

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
[Range(0, 99999999)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Id is required.")]
public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation message and int range are not part of the contract. So You don't break clients. But if client waits for some specific error message and You send another it will be broken logic but not contract anyway

Comment: But if i change the message, clients should update their references isn't it?

Comment: it's not required. If client app has no reference to `RangeAttribute` and `RequiredAttribute` of this contract it will be identical case

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but what "broken logic means"?

Comment: `if (response.ErrorMessage == "errorMessage1")` on client side and `response.ErrorMessage = "errorMessage2"` on server side. Error message literals compare in other words